# JSP Set attribute does not work

Tags: jsp, setattribute

I'm trying to pass an attribute (result) to the url using this piece of code. Unfortunately the parameter is null and does not contain the result data.

```
request.setAttribute("result", result);
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: You're confusing attributes and parameters. Where is the code reading the attribute (and finding it's null)?

Comment: Im sorry, indeed attribute is not what i want (Please excuse me im new to jsp). I just need to pass a value through the url parameters

Comment: Why would you use a parameter to pass a value to a JSP you forward to? An attribute is the right thing to use. In the JSP, just use `${result}`. The URL is useful to pass string values, in a GET request from the browser to the server. Not to pass arbitrary information from a server component to another server component both handling the same request.

Comment: Right, i got it, i was really confused. It works just fine now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`request.getAttribute("result")` gives you the value stored in `result` . Also make sure that you type cast the `result` to corresponding data type, if it's an integer type cast it to a wrapper class `Integer`.  You can achieve that by doing the following; `Integer temp = new Integer(result)`, and then further getting the attribute.

```
Integer recVal= (Integer) request.getAttribute("result");
```